# Recommended approach for handling non-authenticated sessions on ServiceStack

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, servicestack

I've an MVC app, with SS integrated for all BLL that has a shopping basket feature. I want anonymous users to be able to add to basket and then continue shopping with basket details intact when they return - so I feel using the ss-pid for sessionId in redis is the best approach.

Could somebody please confirm if I'm tackling this right, and if so, how do I enable this functionality? (I can't see anyway to use ss-pid by default).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the Session Cookies to store Unauthenticated User Info then you'll want to set:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(...) {
    GenerateNewSessionCookiesOnAuthentication = false
});
```

So when the user does authenticate it preserves the existing cookies, otherwise you'll want to set and use your own Cookies which are unaffected when a User Logs in.

The SessionBag is a good solution for this that uses the Users Session Cookies to store session data for UnAuthenticated users, e.g. you can populate a custom POCO with something like:

```
var unAuthInfo = SessionBag.Get<UnAuthInfo>() ?? new UnAuthInfo();
unAuthInfo.CustomInfo = request.CustomInfo;
SessionBag.Set(unAuthInfo);
```

Then when a User Authenticates, retrieve the info from the Session Bag and add it on your Typed Custom UserSession using the `OnAuthenticated()` event, e.g:

```
public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
{
    [DataMember]
    public string CustomInfo { get; set; }

    public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, 
        IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        var unAuthInfo = authService.GetSessionBag().Get<UnAuthInfo>();

        if (unAuthInfo != null)
            this.CustomInfo = unAuthInfo.CustomInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming I want to use the SS session cookies, is there a way to make anon users use the ss-pid session id by default?

Comment: @richardwhatever either change the [ss-opt Session Cookie](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions) to `ss-opt=perm` or you can force it with `var sessionBag = new SessionFactory.SessionCacheClient(Cache, Request.GetPermanentSessionId());`

Comment: When I set ss-opt=perm it doesn't seem to be early enough in the initial (fresh user, no cookies) request, and as such the session is created in redis with the ss-id. The response then contains the ss-opt=perm, and then on the next request a new anon user session is created this time using the ss-pid, leaving the ss-id session redundant in the cache.  How do I ensure a fresh user request is immediately stored with ss-pid?

Comment: Add a Glogal Request Filter to always check to see if `ss-opt=perm`, if not call `IRequest.SessionOptionsKey("perm")`.

Comment: I got this to work by adding the following code before I save the session within the `OnCreated(IRequest httpReq)` method of my CustomUserSession:

`httpReq.AddSessionOptions(SessionOptions.Permanent);
httpReq.GenerateNewSessionCookies(this);`

This then forces the first request to use ss-pid, without the overhead of checking all future requests. Do you feel this is a good solution?

Comment: @richardwhatever checking a dictionary by key isn't really an overhead, but sure if that works go for it :)

Comment: Lol, yes, point taken! Thanks :)